# What could have caused the MOSFET to fail in this high-side switching circuit?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-design, circuit-protection

I was trying to help my friend fix an issue with his car not getting a signal to the coil (obviously this isn't the correct fix, but it has had the car running previously).

The circuit is driving the trigger of a car's coil pack, is driven by the distributor with around 12VDC.

[image]

R1 is 3.3k

R2 is also 3.3k

PC817 optoisolator

IRF9520 PMOS

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8HlZo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

12v is enough for more than 30-50ma that the trigger pulls from datasheet

MOSFET failed with 1300 ohms gate to drain, 1100 gate to source.

Bench testing with 11.6v without the mosfet when opto is off, gate has 11.6v, on, 0.24v, seems to be working fine.

I'll spare you the details of when the mosfet is installed since it's failed.

He doesn't have an oscilloscope to test for voltages and claims the diode in the mosfet should be sufficient, what other options do we have to protect the mosfet and improve the circuit?

Comment: yes, R2 was 3.3k.

Comment: Ad a schematic. There's a drawing tool button right there in the question editor.

Comment: What brand/model is the car?

Comment: Schematic added there was no optoisolator so those are just the led and transistor next to each other. Car is a 1993 Audi 80.

Comment: In schematic, where are 1300 ohms gate to drain, 1100 gate to source?

Comment: That is what the mosfet measured after it failed, sorry.

Comment: Are you sure you need a PMOS, i.e switch the 12v and not gnd? Shouldn't the 12v be always presnt and then you disconnect gnd - NPN or NMOS use?

Comment: The circuit looks approximately right but Autistic is absolutely correct that the 12V supply will have spikes ... possibly up to 80V. Which won't do the gate any good. (I would prefer a 12V or 15V zener)

Comment: Do you have a capacitor in the coil pack?  It should be noted that ignition coils are generally driven with IGBT's rather than MOSFETs, The miller capacitance is too high in MOSFETS. Also your circuit has no means to discharge miller capacitance, so the MOSFET will turn off real slooooooooooow. The diode in the mosfet is NOT sufficient to handle ignition coil repetitive spikes , it is only 100v avalanche rated at 1joule, , You need a higher voltage rated MOSFET, the ignition coil needs to develop upto 600v on the primary..

Comment: @BobT, I believe the coil pack works like a transistor, see below (pin 2), we are not driving either coil directly, but rather, the coil itself is handling that: http://www.s2central.com/ds_N_N70.html

Comment: Ok If the "POS" is doing all teh hard work, then I would be looking at the ground lead, the ground from the coil unit needs to be connected to the vehicle gnd and the spark plug outer case, all in close proximity. If you have just a loosely wired ground connection, and the spark plug arcs to a different earth, then you will put large spikes all around the place.

Comment: Your MOSFET failure mode is consistent with a punch through of the gate insulation , the IRF9530 has an avalanche diode that would be sufficient for "normal transients" . The gate oxide can be damaged by excessive voltage on the gate , this can sometimes occur when the MOSFET is OFF, by rapidly reducing the voltage between S and D , the high dV/dT couples from the drain into the gate via the miller capacitor. a zener on the gate should fix that. A 1000uF capacitor on the 12v will stop transients on that lead.

Comment: your question is not really clear to me.  Are you saying that this circuit operated correctly and now does not function as intended?  and the trouble shooting you have done is to inspect the mosfet ? and reporting the resistances inside the mosfet?  

it would be helpful to try and make you question clearer.  

also it sounds like you mosfet failed due to no fly back diode connected across you potentially inductive load.

Answer (score 11):

M1 could blow up if the Gate Source voltage is too much. Autoelectric systems are full of spikes. Place a zener between gate source of M1 to clamp the gate below the gate source rating. For example if the Vgs rating is 20VDC then a 18Volt zener would suffice. Load inductance is always present. This causes drain voltage spikes at turnoff which could exceed the avalanche rating of M1. Use a freewheel diode or snubber or clamp to adress this. If your load had a short M1 would blow up. The high prospective fault currents would exceed the current rating of M1. Normal fuses are too slow to protect mosfets. Consider some form of current limit to protect M1.

Answer (score 2):

Check on the secondary side for loose connections, corrosion, bad plug wire, etc.  The secondary voltage driving the spark plug is reflected back to the primary when the MOSFET turns off, and a poor connection or open circuit on the secondary side could cause a voltage spike exceeding the rating of the MOSFET.